# MUI v5 sx prop type error in TabPanel component

Tags: typescript, material-ui

I am using MUI for the first time with TypeScript and I am getting an error on the new `sx` prop. Take a look at the screenshot below on the error displayed by Typescript.
[image]

The funny thing is that I am only getting this error on the `TabPanel` Component because I have used it on other MUI components with no problem.
Below is my code

```js
/* eslint-disable react/require-default-props */
import * as React from 'react';
import Tabs from '@mui/material/Tabs';
import Tab from '@mui/material/Tab';
import Typography from '@mui/material/Typography';
import Box from '@mui/material/Box';

interface TabPanelProps {
  children?: React.ReactNode;
  index: number;
  value: number;
}

function TabPanel(props: TabPanelProps) {
  const { children, value, index, ...other } = props;

  return (
    <div
      role="tabpanel"
      hidden={value !== index}
      id={`simple-tabpanel-${index}`}
      aria-labelledby={`simple-tab-${index}`}
      {...other}
    >
      {value === index && (
        <Box sx={{ p: 3 }}>
          <Typography>{children}</Typography>
        </Box>
      )}
    </div>
  );
}

function a11yProps(index: number) {
  return {
    id: `simple-tab-${index}`,
    'aria-controls': `simple-tabpanel-${index}`
  };
}

export default function MenteeVolunteerTabs() {
  const [value, setValue] = React.useState(0);

  const handleChange = (event: React.SyntheticEvent, newValue: number) => {
    setValue(newValue);
  };

  return (
    <Box sx={{ width: '100%' }}>
      <Box sx={{ borderBottom: 1, borderColor: 'divider' }}>
        <Tabs value={value} onChange={handleChange} aria-label="basic tabs example">
          <Tab label="Volunteer" {...a11yProps(0)} />
          <Tab label="Mentee" {...a11yProps(1)} />
        </Tabs>
      </Box>
      <TabPanel value={value} index={0} sx={{ backgroundColor: '#F4F6F7' }}>
        Item One
      </TabPanel>
      <TabPanel value={value} index={1}>
        Item Two
      </TabPanel>
    </Box>
  );
}
```

Kindly help solve this error

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`TabPanel` is not a MUI component. It's a custom component that you copy from the docs. (I assume from [here](https://mui.com/components/tabs/#basic-tabs))

```
function TabPanel(props) {
  const { children, value, index, ...other } = props;

  return (
    <div
      role="tabpanel"
      hidden={value !== index}
      id={`simple-tabpanel-${index}`}
      aria-labelledby={`simple-tab-${index}`}
      {...other}
    >
      {value === index && (
        <Box sx={{ p: 3 }}>
          <Typography>{children}</Typography>
        </Box>
      )}
    </div>
  );
}
```

To add `sx` prop to your custom component, you can use [`styled()`](https://mui.com/system/styled/#main-content):

```
type TabPanelProps = {
  children: React.ReactNode;
  index: number;
  value: number;
};

const TabPanel = styled((props: TabPanelProps) => {
  const { children, value, index, ...other } = props;

  return (
    <div
      role="tabpanel"
      hidden={value !== index}
      id={`simple-tabpanel-${index}`}
      aria-labelledby={`simple-tab-${index}`}
      {...other}
    >
      {value === index && (
        <Box sx={{ p: 3 }}>
          <Typography>{children}</Typography>
        </Box>
      )}
    </div>
  );
})<TabPanelProps>();
```

[image: Codesandbox Demo]

Comment: Thanks for this.  I never noted that. 